# how can i use preg_match and get value?

Tags: php

i am using this code and its getting No ending delimiter '/' found

```
if (preg_match("/", $desp))
{
    $dp = explode("/",$desp);

    $dp1 = $dp[0];
    $dp2 = $dp[1];
}
```

in `$desp` i have value like `abc/xyz` then it should be like

```
$dp1 = abc
$dp2 = xyz
```

so what is the right code thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use strpos instead.  Anyway, the reason you're getting that error is because the pattern doesn't have delimiters.

An example of the pattern with delimeters:

```
if (preg_match("~/~", $desp))
```

What you should do, however:

```
if (strpos($desp, '/') !== false)
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like that

```
$str = "abc/xyz";
$pattern = '/\//';
if(preg_match($pattern, $str))
    echo "foo";
```

you had to escape your slash with a backslash to make it work

Comment: "you had to escape your slash with a backslash to make it work"  No, he needed delimiters.  The slash is only needed because it's the same character as the delimiters.

Comment: you're right i'm  so used to use backslash as delimiters, that i forget it :D